# Assign multiple pandas columns from list output

Tags: python, pandas

Situation: trying to split one column of a pandas df into two separate columns, without changing the original data - if possible using the `.assign()` method.

Below produces the expected result but each column requires its own assignment expression and feels like the wrong way of doing it.

```py
pets = pd.DataFrame({'observation': ['black,cat', 'brown,dog']})

(
    pets
    .assign(colour = pets['observation'].str.split(',', expand=True)[0],
            animal = pets['observation'].str.split(',', expand=True)[1])
    .drop(columns='observation')
)
```

Below feels more like the right way: `.str.split(...,expand=True)` results in a list so a list of variable names feels like what I should provide.

```py
# throws error
(
    pets
    .assign(colour, animal = pets['observation'].str.split(',', expand=True))
    .drop(columns='observation')
)

# throws error
(
    pets
    .assign([colour, animal] = pets['observation'].str.split(',', expand=True))
    .drop(columns='observation')
)
```

```
NameError: name 'colour' is not defined
```

```py
   .assign([colour, animal] = pets['observation'].str.split(',', expand=True))
            ^
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

Comment: Can you remove from question `(I'd like to use the .assign() method)` ? Because accepted solution NOT use it.

Comment: quite right. should be changed now. The previous want for the .assign() method was because it doesn't change the original data, which the accepted solution does not. Thanks

Comment: Ya, because now it is confused - need `assign` from my answer, but accepted something else? So it means dont need `assign`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a new dataframe, you can `rename` the columns using a simple dictionary:

```
cols = ['colour', 'animal']
new_df = (pets['observation']
              .str.split(',', expand=True)
              .rename(columns=dict(enumerate(cols)))
         )
```

output:

```
  colour animal
0  black    cat
1  brown    dog
```

Assuming you want to use a pipeline, you can craft a custom function and use `pipe`:

```
def split(df):
    df = df.copy()
    cols = ['colour', 'animal']
    df[cols] = df['observation'].str.split(',', expand=True)
    return df

(
    pets
    .pipe(split)
    .drop(columns='observation')
)
```

*NB. this is only a simple pipeline example, of course you can craft a more interesting function with parameters*

```
def split(df, col_to_split, cols):
    df = df.copy()
    df[cols] = df[col_to_split].str.split(',', expand=True)
    return df

(
    pets
    .pipe(split, col_to_split='observation', cols=['colour', 'animal'])
    .drop(columns='observation')
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful but changes the initial pets df, which is why I wanted to use the `.assign()` method as that forces a copy.

Comment: @dcurrie27 you can add the functionality in the custom function ;) see my edit

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
def app(s):
    s['colour']=s[0][0]
    s['animal']=s[0][1]
    return s

pets['observation']=pets.apply(lambda x: x[0].split(','),axis=1)
pets=pets.apply(app,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create dictioanry of `Series` by [`DataFrame.set_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) and [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
d = pets['observation'].str.split(',', expand=True).set_axis(cols, axis=1).to_dict('Series')
df1 = pets.assign(**d)
print (df1)
  observation colour animal
0   black,cat  black    cat
1   brown,dog  brown    dog
```

If possible assign to original DataFrame is possible use:

```
cols = ['colour', 'animal']
pets[cols] = pets['observation'].str.split(',', expand=True)
print (pets)
  observation colour animal
0   black,cat  black    cat
1   brown,dog  brown    dog
```

If need new DataFrame:

```
cols = ['colour', 'animal']
df = pets['observation'].str.split(',', expand=True).set_axis(cols, axis=1)
print (df)
  colour animal
0  black    cat
1  brown    dog
```